# What is Dean Winters' character Avi's function in John Wick?

Tags: character, john-wick

In the movie John Wick (2014), we meet an associate of Viggo Tarasov named Avi, played by Dean Winters (maybe best known from Allstate Insurance's Mayhem ads).

In the few scenes that we see Avi, he seems to provide little of value to Viggo:

- When Viggo is chastising his son, Avi seems to be easily bothered and is trying to get away from the scene
- At the end, before the final fight scene, Avi is seen to not even have a gun of his own.  He asks for one from Viggo
- From the interplay of Viggo handing his gun to Avi, we see that Avi can easily be toyed with.  This would also indicate that he doesn't have a strong personality to be Viggo's consiglieri
- Avi is dispensed fairly easily by John Wick

Viggo has bodyguards, who are each more qualified it would seem than Avi to stand over him.

Also, doing some research on the John Wick Wiki site, it claims that Avi is a marksman.  If that is so, I don't understand why he isn't always carrying.

For reference, Avi is at the left here:

[image]

Comment: My impression when watching the movie was either lawyer or accountant. He's definitely got that kind of vibe; he's involved in the operations, and relatively important, but also didn't seem like a hands-on, involved in the actual dirty work type. That's not based on anything I actually recall from the movie though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avi is Viggo Tarasov's friend and personal counsel. He is also high ranking within the Tarasov crime family with at least one team of men and a helicopter crew on standby.

Due to Avi being familiar with John Wick but not the level of danger he actually represents as shown later in the movie, it's highly likely Avi joined the crime family after John Wick's initial cleanup of competitors.